# Hang fire background jobs gives SQL exception : Login Failed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, hangfire, hangfire-sql

Tutorial I followed - https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html

Configure services in startup class

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobs)
    {
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
            backgroundJobs.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!")); 
}
```

> SqlException: Cannot open database "HangfireTest" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'PENGUIN\PC'.

When I run the application I got this exception?

Comment: How is your application running? Is `PC` an actual (human) user-account or is it a Service Account?

Comment: Windows User Account

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing connection string in apsettings.json file, If you need to find out connection string right click on data base instance of SQl server object explorer of visual studio -> properties and get connection string. This connection string should be with placed with appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"ApplicationDbContext": "server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ApplicationDbContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"HangfireConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```